# What is this delta wing aircraft parked at NASA Ames Research Center at Moffett Field?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What is the aircraft shown at these coordinates? https://goo.gl/maps/VTc153EacEL2

This is at NASA Ames Research Center at Moffett Field. Per the [Ames map](https://historicproperties.arc.nasa.gov/map_bldglocator/map_bldglocator_guide_2013.pdf) it is located north behind building N-127 (Warehouse) and west of the VTOL pad.

It has a dome canopy and a delta wing configuration. It is approximately the size of a fighter aircraft. A very blurry picture of the tail is visible by using Google Streetview from the Moffett golf course and looking west across runway 41R.

[image]

Comment: Delta-wing aircraft tend to look pretty similar from top-down; do you have any other photos of it from another angle?  That might help identify it, either by showing aircraft markings, and/or a better view from the side to pick out more features.

Comment: @RalphJ - No. Just another one of those things found while goofing off on Google Earth. Google 3D does somewhat show a side profile but I question its accuracy.

Comment: The F-106 seems like a close match and there is one listed in the NASA inventory at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NASA_aircraft

Comment: Except the wing planform doesn't match.

Comment: Could it be a B-58?

Comment: @MikeBrass No, the B-58 wing shape is different + the underwing engines are very obvious from a top-down view.

Comment: The challenge here is that its clearly parked in a boneyard. Engines could be off. It's also NASA boneyard, it seems possible that it's a standard platform with modifications.

Comment: Bonus question:  what is the plane beside it?

Comment: @Freiheit  Definitely not a F-106.  The wing on the mystery aircraft is taller than it is wide and the f-106 is almost exactly as tall as it is wide.  The wind tips are also flattened in your picture as opposed to the F-106 but I suppose a saw could have fixed it that way...

Comment: I don't agree with the assessment that the F-106 is similar. The wingtips are pointy for the 106, rounded for the one in the picture. Given the surrounding scraps, it could be a mock-up, rather than an actual aircraft.

Comment: And its nose is blunt.

Comment: Looking at the 3D view in Google maps it very much looks like a F5D with a modified wing. However there were only 4 F5D's built of which two went to NASA. Both are now in musea. The F5D was flow with modified wings by NASA, in a research programme for supersonic transport. Perhaps it is a windtunnel model for studies that we are looking at?

Comment: Maybe we should measure the leading edge sweep angle and type the value into Google together with "sweep angle", "NASA" and "delta wing".

Comment: If the pinned aircraft "is the size of a fighter", then the one next to it must be the size of a lawn dart!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a STOVL E-7 Model.. It is not an actual aircraft.

https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/e-7-stovl-fighter-model-testing-in-ames-40x80ft-wind-tunnel-tom-trower/RQEHhSh_zF3TuQ?ms=%7B%22x%22%3A0.5%2C%22y%22%3A0.5%2C%22z%22%3A9.425586796493714%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A1.2166568742655705%2C%22height%22%3A1.2375000000000007%7D%7D

[image]

The enlarged photo shows the inlet duct covers. It looks like they left the lifting cables just laying on top. This is a model that never flew.

[image]

Comment: It would do a lot to include some text and/or an image from your link. That link could go dead in an internet minute leaving your answer useless. Please feel free to [edit] something in to bring a little more substance.

Comment: I'm not convinced-- the wind tunnel model appears to have sharper front and back corners on the wingtips than the photo in the original post.

Comment: @quietflyer Google messes up photos when they try to create 3D. If you look at just the white wing tips on enlargement, they match the model pretty closely.

Comment: [This photo](https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/general-dynamics-e-7-stovl-fighter-model-fabrication-at-ames-model-shop-tom-trower/CQEqewbv1VqAkQ) would indicate that the aircraft in question is the same size as the Wind Tunnel model.

Comment: @Pilothead -- ok I see that now..

Answer (score 5):

I think @DeltaLima nailed it in comments. I'd happily accept an answer if he/she would care to post one.

From: https://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/multimedia/imagegallery/F-5D/F-5D_proj_desc.html

> After the Dyna-Soar program was canceled in December 1963 the F5D-1
>   (708) went to Ames Research Center, installed with a ogee wing for an
>   evaluation for Concorde Supersonic Transport wing study. The F5D-1
>   (802) stayed on at NASA Flight Research Center contributing to various
>   tests. It became a flight simulator for the M2-F2, and a chase for the
>   lifting bodies until 1970. In May 1970 the Douglas F5D-1 Skylancer
>   (NASA 802) was retired and donated to the Neil A. Armstrong Museum in
>   Wapakoneta, Ohio, to rest beside the light plane in which Armstrong
>   learned to fly.

This shows that an airframe was at Ames and it had a modified wing. I think it suggests that the airframe never left Ames.

Comment: I found that same text and researched where [708](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/history/where_are_they_now/F5D_708.html) and [802](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/history/where_are_they_now/F5D_802.html) are now. Both are, according to the NASA links, in a museum. So it must be something else.

Comment: Definitely not. Look at the NASA report, Figure 2 https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660003728.pdf

Comment: This is not an F5. The wingtip is much more round, and the modification made by NASA made the wing look like half an infinity symbol, not straight as in your Google photo.  https://youtu.be/zRYZPaHY7rU?t=22